# NodeJS Construct a custom object without requiring the file

Tags: node.js, class, object, instantiation

Is there a way in nodejs to define a custom object type in it's own file, then instantiate it anywhere else in the codebase without needing to require in the file?

For example, every time I create a new map somewhere, I don't have to require in the map definition. I want to be able to do

```
var user = new User();
```

from anywhere without requiring in the definition.

Comment: Not if you're going to follow the node.js modular conventions where each module stands on it's own and does not have hidden dependencies or some global environment that it depends upon.  Just `require()` in the module for `User` anywhere you're going to use it.  That's how you take the most advantage of modules, reuse, testability, explicit dependencies, etc...  Just get used to it in node.js.  If you're going to use it, `require()` it in!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to require a dependency everywhere then you could use Dependency Injection. Dependency Injection is a pattern for passing dependencies or common information from one context to another.

The power of Dependency Injection is decoupling the Dependency itself with resolving and/or initializing that Dependency. In JavaScript, [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) can be used to hide configuration/initialization details of a Dependency by locking in their context to the scope that created them. This means that your files implementing the Dependency don't need to be concerned with how to get it initialized (ie. a config) which, probably also means more thing it needs to require.

Below is an example of how a `User` can be required in one file, injected into a separate file and then be used as if it were required within the file it was injected to. I chose to use an Express Server and Dependency Injection into a Router as the example because a popular reason to use Node.js is to build a Web API. For another example of Dependency Injection, see this [blog post](https://blog.risingstack.com/fundamental-node-js-design-patterns/) from RisingStack Engineering (you'll need to scroll down to the Dependency Injection section).

The example has 3 files

- `lib/models/User.js`

  - This is the module that is Injected into our `UserRouter`
- `/routes/user.js`

  - This is the UserRouter and it returns a function that accepts a `models` object which, contains all Models the `UserRouter` needs. Once the router is created it is returned for use within an Express Server
- `server.js`.

  - The Express Server that is going to be responsible for injecting the `User` Model into the `UserRouter` so it can create new users in a cache.

#### lib/models/User

```
class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

module.exports = User
```

#### routes/user.js

```
const Router = require('express').Router

const UserRouter = models => {
    // Use Destructuring to get the User model from the models object passed into the Router
    // You can use regular ES5 for this as well: var User = models.User
    const {User} = models
    const router = new Router()

    const users = []

    // Return all users in cache
    router.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).json({users}))

    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
        const {name} = (req.body || {})
        if (!name) {
            return res.status(400).send('A User must have a name')
        }

        // Create the new User
        let newUser = new User(name)

        // add it to the users cache
        users.push(newUser)

        // return 201 CREATED and send the user as the message body
        return res.status(201).json(newUser)
    })

    // Return the router instance
    return router
}

module.exports = UserRouter
```

#### server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337

// require our UserRouter 
const UserRouter = require('./routes/user')

// import the User model
const User = require('./lib/models/User')

// create an object called Models with the User now as a property
const Models = {User}

const server = express()

// Inject the Models directly into the UserRouter
server.use('/users', UserRouter(Models))

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`))
```